# Makefile:10: recipe for target 'modules' failed on multiple debian distros

Tags: linux, makefile, debian

**FIXED** 
The problem was that I had spaces somewhere in the path to my source directory.
In this case, "Source Builds" had a space and screwed everything up.
**Make sure you don't have any spaces anywhere in your folder names between root and your make directory.**

So this error:
make[1]: ** No rule to make target **'Builds/** digimend-kernel-drivers-master'.  Stop.
Came from the space in:
 ~/**Source Builds**/digimend-kernel-drivers-master

debian wheezy, jessie and now simplice 6 sid

I installed the build essentials package
the linux headers package for my kernel

ive tried on kernel 3.2.04, 3.16 and now 3.12

gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-8) 
GNU Make 4.0

this is what i get when i try to make.

```
willy@semplice:~/Source Builds/digimend-kernel-drivers-master$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.12-7.semplice.0-desktop-686/build SUBDIRS=/home/willy/Source Builds/digimend-kernel-drivers-master modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-7.semplice.0-desktop-686'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Builds/digimend-kernel-drivers-master'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-7.semplice.0-desktop-686'
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Heres the makefile

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
obj-m := hid-huion.o hid-uclogic.o
else
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
UDEV_RULES := /lib/udev/rules.d/70-hid-rebind.rules
DEPMOD_CONF := /etc/depmod.d/digimend.conf
HID_REBIND := /sbin/hid-rebind
modules modules_install clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) $@
install: modules_install
    install -D -m 0644 digimend.conf $(DEPMOD_CONF)
    depmod -a
    install hid-rebind $(HID_REBIND)
    install -m 0644 hid-rebind.rules $(UDEV_RULES)
    udevadm control --reload
uninstall:
    rm -vf $(UDEV_RULES) $(HID_REBIND) $(DEPMOD_CONF) \
        /lib/modules/*/extra/hid-huion.ko \
        /lib/modules/*/extra/hid-uclogic.ko
    udevadm control --reload
    depmod -a
endif
```

what is going on here... I am getting sad

Comment: Either close the question or file your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont know how

Answer (score 1):

**FIXED** 
The problem was that I had spaces somewhere in the path to my source directory.
In this case, "Source Builds" had a space and screwed everything up.
**Make sure you don't have any spaces anywhere in your folder names between root and your make directory.**

So this error:
make[1]: ** No rule to make target **'Builds/** digimend-kernel-drivers-master'.  Stop.
Came from the space in:
 ~/**Source Builds**/digimend-kernel-drivers-master
 – user4369678